# define ObservableCollection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to developing with C#/WPF. I want to add elements in combo box but when I use comboBoxName.Items.add(item) it does not add the item. I decided to use ObservableCollection but when I define something like

```
ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

I get a compile error with "the type or name ObservableCollection could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)". What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `using System.Collections.ObjectModel` at start of file or use `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This type has been defined since .NET 3.0, and was supplied in WindowsBase.dll.

With the introduction of the v4.0 CLR, the type moved into System.dll.

Depending on the framework version of your project, you'll need to reference a different DLL to have access to this type.